# Merging content of multiple files into one in a loop

Tags: shell, unix

I have multiples files in a dir which i want to merge at runtime like for example,
file1.dat
file2.dat
file3.dat
file4.dat
I am trying to take file1.dat and trying to merge the content of the remaining files in it. I have code in the script but I'm not sure it's not writing the content of other files in it.

When I run this line `sed -e '2,${/^Ticket/' -e '}' $i > $INP_FILE` separately it works. But in my script inside the loop it's not working, the final file will have content from the last file only. Can someone please suggest what is wrong with it.

Comment: Good that you have shown your efforts, please do add samples of input and expected output in your question too; to make it more clear, thank you.

Comment: More information may be needed. But I see one thing that may be a problem. You use ">" to redirect the output to a file. If this is inside a loop, you are overwriting the content of the file every pass of the loop. Put ">>" or move the ">" after the end of the loop (after the `done` in a `for` o a `while` loop).